# Compute the cohomology of $\mathrm{Hom} (\Omega^*(M),\Omega^*(M))$

Tags: differential-topology, hochschild-cohomology, chain-complexes

Let $M$ be a compact smooth manifold. And particularly I am interested in the case the torus $M=T^n$.

Consider the de Rham complex $(\Omega^*(M), d)$ and the cochain complex
$$
C:=\mathrm{Hom} (\Omega^*(M),\Omega^*(M))
$$
with the differential map $\delta$ given by
$$
\delta(f)=d \circ f - f\circ d$$

> **Question**: what is the cohomology $H^*(C,\delta)$? And, what should be the right tool to do the computation? Is this cohomology related to the usual de Rham cohomology $H^*_{dR}(M)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since everything is linear over the field $\mathbb{R}$, $\Omega^*(M)$ is chain homotopy equivalent to $H^*_{dR}(M)$ endowed with the trivial differential, hence the cohomology of your complex $C$ is just $\operatorname{Hom}(H^*_{dR}(M),H^*_{dR}(M))$. This identification is not natural in $M$ though.